# Service account credential for Dataflow pipline options

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Upgrading from Dataflow 1.9 to Beam 0.4.0. The methods on GcpOptions to set service account name (`setServiceAccountName`) and key file (`setServiceAccountKeyFile`) are no longer available. The closest alternative is `setGcpCredential`.

To manually create the GoogleCredential, what will be the appropriate scopes to use? My pipelines need to access PubSub, Datastore, and BigQuery, potentially Cloud Storage.

```java
new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
    .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
    .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccount)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)  // what will be the scopes?
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12file)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe based on [this list](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes) that all of those should be accessible using the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` scope.